# $> bash script.sh ... does the forked bash process in turn create a sub-shell?

Tags: bash, shell, subprocess, subshell

If I run:

```
$> bash script.sh
```

a fork-and-exec happens to run the bash binary. Does that process execute script.sh or does it create a sub-shell in turn in the same way that

```
$> ./script.sh
```

first creates a sub-shell to execute the script?

Comment: Forking and creating a subshell are the same thing.

Comment: Essentially, the only difference between those two commands is that the OS runs `bash` with `script.sh` as the first argument for you (assuming a shebang of `#!/bin/bash`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bash` process that runs `bash script.sh` executes the script directly, not as a second layer of fork and exec.  Obviously, individual commands within the script are forked and executed separately, but not the script itself.

You could use `ps` to show that.  For example, `script.sh` might contain:

```
tty
echo $$
sleep 20
```

You could run that and in another terminal window run `ps -ft tty0` (if the `tty` command indicated `tty0`), and you'd see the shell in which you ran the `bash script.sh` command, the shell which is running `script.sh` and the `sleep` command.

#### Example

In `ttys000`:

```
$ bash script.sh
/dev/ttys000
65090
$
```

In `ttys001`:

```
$ ps -ft ttys000
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0  2422  2407   0  9Jul14 ttys000    0:00.13 login -pfl jleffler /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /bin/bash
199484  2428  2422   0  9Jul14 ttys000    0:00.56 -bash
199484 65090  2428   0  3:58PM ttys000    0:00.01 bash script.sh
199484 65092 65090   0  3:58PM ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 20
$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pstree` or `ps -fax` to look at the process tree. In your case when specifying bash as a (forked) command with a script parameter it will not (need) to fork a subshell as running with "command file" is one mode of operation (if not used -c).

BTW: you can also use `exec sh script.sh` to replace your current shell process with the new sub shell.

When you call a shell script without the `source` (or `.`) command, it will run in a subshell. This is the case for your second line. If you want to run the script in the current one, you would need to use `. ./script.sh`.